# ProtoParquetWriter don't write falses, 0s and empty strings

Tags: protocol-buffers, parquet, protobuf-java

In the following example:

```java
  try (ParquetWriter<Example> writer =
        new ProtoParquetWriter<>(
            new Path("file:/tmp/foo.parquet"),
            Example.class,
            SNAPPY,
            DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE,
            DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)) {
      writer.write(
          Example.newBuilder()
              .setTs(System.currentTimeMillis())
              .setTenantId("tenant")
              .setSomeFlag(false)
              .setSomeInt(1)
              .setOtherInt(0)
              .build());
    }
  }
```

And example `.proto` file:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package com.example;

message Example {
  uint64 ts = 1;
  string tenantId = 2;
  bool someFlag = 3;
  int32 someInt = 4;
  int32 otherInt = 2;
}
```

The resulting parquet file won't have the fields `someFlag` and `otherInt` because they are `false` and `0` respectively.

Is there a way to make it write it anyway or should I handle this on the reader side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In proto3, presence tracking was not enabled historically, and the only presence rule was around zero defaults. Fortunately this changed recently in new versions of protoc. The `optional` keyword can now be used in from of fields in proto3 to enable this. So: add `optional`, and any compliant implementation should do what you want. The defaults are still zero/false/etc, but if they are explicitly set: they are serialized.

```cs
syntax = "proto3";
package com.example;

message Example {
  optional uint64 ts = 1;
  optional string tenantId = 2;
  optional bool someFlag = 3;
  optional int32 someInt = 4;
  optional int32 otherInt = 2; // [sic]
}
```

Also, the second 2 should be a 5

Comment: do you know in which version? I tried on latest protobuf-java 3.x (3.15.8) and it won't even generate the java classes, failing with: " Explicit 'optional' labels are disallowed in the Proto3 syntax. To define 'optional' fields in Proto3, simply remove the 'optional' label, as fields are 'optional' by default."

Comment: @caarlos0 that was enabled by default in 3.15.0 - see the release notes

Comment: It turns out my maven plugin was using an older version despite I'm asking for a newer one... Yeah, this fixes it. Thanks!